# Problem with solving ODE: $t \frac{dx}{dt} + (1+ \alpha t)x = t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $t> 0$, I have the inhomogeneous equation:

$t \frac{dx}{dt} + (1+ \alpha t)x = t$.

I am asked to make it homogeneous and then determine the general solution. However, I am confused since the equation is not of the general form:

$\frac{dx}{dt} + a(t)x = b(t)$.

I know I should set $b(t)$ equal to $0$ to make an equation homogeneous. My confusion is about $\frac{dx}{dt}$ being multiplied by $t$.

Am I supposed to change the equation into $\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{(1+ \alpha t)x}{t} = 1$, and then into $\frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{(1+ \alpha t)x}{t} = 0$? This does not seem right since there is no longer a function of $t$ on the right hand side (when the right hand side equals 1).

Comment: You're exactly right. The RHS is still a (constant) function of $t,$ no problem there.

Comment: @ABC After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to notice
$$
\frac{d}{dt}tx = x + t\frac{dx}{dt}
$$
which we can look at the original equation we can see that the above is embedded into the equation.
$$
t\frac{dx}{dt}  + x + atx = t
$$
or
$$
\frac{d}{dt}tx  + atx = t
$$
we can now set $u = tx$
$$
\frac{du}{dt} + au = t
$$
which you can now proceed with.

Comment: Shouldn't the third equation be $\frac{d}{dt}tx + (1+at)x = t$?

Comment: I replaced the terms in the second equation with the first equation. Should all check out.

Answer (score 0):

- Let solve first for $\alpha=0$.

We get $\displaystyle t\dot x+x=t$ and by dividing by $t$ (since $t>0$) $\displaystyle \quad\dot x+\frac xt=1$

The homogeneous equation can be rearranged $\displaystyle \frac{\dot x}x=-\frac 1t$ whose solutions are $\displaystyle x=\frac ct$

Since $x=t$ is an easy particular solution, we get $$x=t+\frac ct$$

- Let solve now for $\alpha\neq 0$.

By the same operation we get $\displaystyle \dot x+\left(\frac{1+\alpha t}t\right)x=1$

The homogeneous equation $\frac{\dot x}x=-\frac 1t-\alpha\quad$ integrates to $\quad\displaystyle x=c\times\frac 1t\times e^{-\alpha t}=\frac{c\,e^{-\alpha t}}t$

But there is no obvious particular solution for the equation with RHS that I can see, so we'll use the variation of the constant method.

$\displaystyle t\dot x+(1+\alpha t)x=\dot c\, e^{-\alpha t}=t\iff \dot c=t\,e^{\alpha t}\iff c=\frac{\alpha t-1}{\alpha^2}e^{\alpha t}$

Finally a particular solution is given by $\displaystyle x=\frac 1\alpha-\frac 1{\alpha^2t}$

And the general solution is $$x=\frac 1{\alpha^2}\left(\alpha+\frac{c e^{-\alpha t}-1}t\right)$$